# How I know the index of specific value in a set

Tags: delphi

I have these codes:

```
    TAPPUGroup = (APP_UG_USERS, APP_UG_SUPER_USERS, APP_UG_ADMINS);
    TAPPUGroups = set of TAPPUGroup;

    TAppUser = record
        UID: integer;
        UName: string;
        UGroup: TAPPUGROUPS;

    end;

...
LoggedUser: TAppUser;
```

I used `include` to add groups to LoggedUser.UGroup, now how I know the index of specific value in TAPPUGroup for example if APP_UG_SUPER_USERS included in LoggedUser.UGroup how I can get it's index in TAPPUGroup ?

**Example:** If LoggedUser.UGroup = APP_UG_SUPER_USERS then I want to return 1 if LoggedUser.UGroup = APP_UG_ADMINS I want to return 2 and so on.

Comment: Are you asking about Ord()?

Comment: @MartynA Yes wait... I get incompatible types when I use i := ord(LoggedUser.UGroup); where i is integer. What I should do ?

Comment: I can't understand the question. Perhaps you can define what you mean by **index**, maybe with some examples.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added an example.

Comment: Your example is not valid because `UGroup` is a set. I don't think you fully understand what a set is.

Comment: There is still a lot of explanation in the comments to the answers. Please add it to the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The example I posted is not a code it is just "explanation".

Comment: A set can hold a **multiple** of enums, thus a check if such a set is equal to a single enum is invalid. If both Martyn's and Remy's answers aren't what you are looking for, then we need to know **exactly** what you are asking. What is the problem and which purpose should the solution fit?

Comment: If you can't explain to us your scenario, how can we answer. Please try harder to make the question clear. Again, do you understand what a set is?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes David :)

Comment: So what is the index of `[APP_UG_USERS, APP_UG_SUPER_USERS, APP_UG_ADMINS]`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I store single value so I though there is a way to get it's index, it seems you understand what I want after all.

Comment: If you store a single value, don't use a set. Use the enumerated type.

Comment: Ok David but I will leave it as it is because in the future I may need to add one user to more than one group.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. Designing for some future change that might never happen. If there's a single value always, use a single value. Anyway, I don't think you want to hear this so I'll stop.

Comment: No David thanks for your useful tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really do want the index of a given enumeration item in the enumeration, all you need to do is just use Ord().

To go the other way, you can use the enumeration name as it it were a function:

```
AGroup := TAPPUGroup(1);
```

Anyway, Ord() is how you find the index of a given enumeration value (like APP_UG_USERS) in a contiguous enumeration declaration.  To find out whether a particular set *instance* contains a given set element, ou use the "if xxx in ..." construct Remy shows, e.g.

```
if APP_UG_USERS in MySet then  ...
```

You can also do this

```
var 
  AValue : TAPPUGroup;
  MySet : TAPPUGroups ;

for AValue:= Low(TAPPUGroup) to High(TAPPUGroup) do
  if AValue in MySet then ...
```

Comment: If I used `ord(LoggedUser.UGroup)` I get incompatible types error

Comment: I think that's because UGroup is a set.  Ord() works on (amongst other things) the individual elements of an enumeration but not on a Set of them - Ord() is meaningless in that context.

Comment: If I store single value in LoggedUser.UGroup is there a way to use ord() with LoggedUser.UGroup ?

Comment: No, because a set containing a single value is still a set to the compiler, and Ord() for does work with sets.  Hang on, give me 2 mins, & I'll add a bit to my answer which may help.

Comment: Thanks Martyna, it seems looping is the only way to get what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the index. To know if a value exists in the Set, use the `in` operator instead:

```
if APP_UG_SUPER_USERS in LoggedUser.UGroup then
```

Comment: I need the index to compare to a value in the database. for example if table1.fieldbyname('ugroup').asinteger = 1 then ....

Comment: The index is meaningless. It is an implementation detail of how enum values are stored within the Set's bits. That is not what you really want in this situation.  If the `ugroup` DB field can only hold one value at a time, then just compare it directly to your enum values: `if Table1.FieldByName('ugroup').AsInteger = APP_UG_SUPER_USERS then`. But if the field can hold multiple values, you need to define a bitmask for your values, not an enum: `const APP_UG_USERS = 1; APP_UG_SUPER_USERS = 2; APP_UG_ADMINS = 4; ... if (Table1.FieldByName('ugroup').AsInteger and APP_UG_SUPER_USERS) <> 0 then`.

Comment: If you absolutely want to use an enum in a Set, then use something more like this: `PByte(@LoggedUser.UGroup)^ := Table1.FieldByName('ugroup').AsInteger; if APP_UG_SUPER_USERS in LoggedUser.UGroup then`.  Sets are compressed, where a Set declared to hold <= 8 values occupies a single byte, thus the use of `PByte`.

Comment: I just posted a sample I have 14 groups and can be increased in the future , what I should use instead of `PByte`.

Comment: I need also the integer of the current group to pass it to SQL query to where clause.

Comment: The number of enum values in the Set declaration dictates the number of bits the Set uses, rounded up to an even multiple of 8. So 14 values is 16 bits, ie a `Word`, so use `PWord` when casting: `Query1.ParamByName('ugroup').AsInteger := PWord(@LoggedUser.UGroup)^;` I would not recommend relying on the internal bit representation of a Set. Query the Set explicitly for the desired values and build up a suitable integer as needed: `var Groups: Integer; Groups := 0; if APP_UG_SUPER_USERS in LoggedUser.UGroup then Groups := Groups + ...; ...  Query1.ParamByName('ugroup').AsInteger := Groups;`

Comment: Thanks, for using `PWord` I get result of 4 if LoggedUser.UGroup has one element at position 2 and I get 32 if LoggedUser.UGroup has one element at position 5 why is that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92205/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-wel).